# Decomposition by Clique Separators

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, separation

Tarjan described a procedure for decomposing a graph using clique separators in "Decomposition by clique separators", RE Tarjan - Discrete mathematics, 1985 - Elsevier.

He also proposed different divide-and-conquer algorithms for various graph problems such as maximum clique, minimum coloring and maximum independent set. An atom is a subgraph of a graph that does not contain a separator. If one can solve the problem efficiently in the atoms (local solutions) then Tarjan describes in the same paper how to extend these local solutions to a global solution. Therefore characterization of the atoms is very important. For example an atom of a chordal graph is a clique and the atoms of an edge intersection graphs of paths in a tree are exactly line graphs of a multigraph.

I am wondering the characterization of atoms for other graph classes like for example disk graphs or AT-free graphs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chvátal and Sbihi (Recognizing Claw-free Perfect Graphs, JCTB 44) described the atoms for the class of claw-free perfect graphs, a.k.a. quasi-line perfect graphs.  This description was later refined by Maffray and Reed, and essentially consists of two classes: "peculiar", which are kind of a special case, and "elementary", which are constructed by modifying the line graph of a bipartite multigraph through an operation called augmentation.

Comment: I am sure that I will find some more results by looking the publications of the same authors. Thank you.

Comment: I should mention that there is another class of graphs, *clique-separable graphs*, whose atoms are the complete multipartite graphs and cliques joined to bipartite graphs.